# Projectile ignores all File markers except .git

Tags: emacs, emacs-projectile

I recently started working with a few projects that either don't have a `.git` directory in their root, or are a subdirectory of a git repo, e.g.

```
parent-project/
  |- .git
  +- my-project/
       |- Cargo.toml
       +- src/main.rs
```

And in all cases I found that Projectile sets the root to the nearest directory containing `.git`, ignoring all other file markers (`Cargo.toml`, `stack.yaml`, etc.) along the way. (In the example above, opening `main.rs` sets the project root to `parent-project` instead of `my-project`).

The [Projectile documentation](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/projects.html#customizing-project-detection) suggests that this should not be the case, so I'm wondering how I can either manually set the project root for each project, or configure Projectile to use the actual file markers.

Comment: Just do `touch .projectile` (i.e. create an empty file named `.projectile`) in the root directory of your project - I think.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it still uses the `parent-project` as the root.